# css/js: fixed position though scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, html, sticky

Does CSS(3) allow me to stick a DIV with position:absolute over the page and keep it e.g. in the middle of the browser window - even when scrolling?

Currently I re-draw and re-position the DIV again and again when the user scrolls up/down/left/right, but maybe css3 has a better way to achieve the same.

Comment: Plain CSS [`position:fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning) can be used to do that. No JavaScript required unless you need it to work in old browsers that don't support it (IE6 for example)

Answer (score 5):

That's what `position:fixed` is for.